# Assign each person a set of essays to read, while prioritizing certain groupings

Tags: algorithm, combinatorics

**Assume:**

1. 10,000 student essays to be read, each associated with a high school
2. 80 readers, with a desired_essay_count and a maximum_essay_limit.
3. Country is split into 300 regions, each belonging to a state (e.g. California 1, California 2, etc.)

**Requirements:**

- Essays coming from a single high school will be assigned to a
  single reader (aka high schools cannot be split up)
- Attempt to keep regions together
- Attempt to keep states together

Are there any algorithms that resemble this set-up? Currently, I'm sorting all essays by state, region, and high school. Then I group the high school essays together and assign them to the next reader in the queue with available space, and repeat until the reader hits the max_essay_limit. Simple, and it leads to a relatively clean solution, but doesn't consider the desired_essay_count at all (meaning readers at the end of the queue end up with few essays to read).

Comment: It seems you have a good start.  Sort the reader queue by desired essay limit (highest to lowest).  If you can't assign a batch to the head of the queue, move them to the back and try again.  Once they've all hit the desired limit, resort based on max limit and continue until all the batches are assigned.  (Or use a genetic algorithm with a fitness function that takes the preferences into account.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would solve this with priority queues.

The first is a queue for groups of essays, which will always give you the largest grouping you have.  You start with groups corresponding to states, in a data structure that can easily be broken out by region or by school.

The second is a queue for readers.  Prioritize this one by how far you are from the desired_essay_count so that you try to assign essays to lightly loaded readers first.

Now the algorithm.

```
while you have groups:
    group = next group in groups
    scanned_readers = empty array
    while you have readers:
       reader = next reader in readers
       if you can comfortably assign group to reader:
           assign group
           put reader back in readers with new priority
           replace scanned_readers into reader
           GO TO NEXT ITERATION of groups loop.
       else:
           put reader into scanned_readers
           put all readers for reader in priority_queue
    if the group can be split:
        split the group into pieces, put them into groups array
    else:
        find a reader who can do it, no matter how much they don't want to.
        (or else give up)
```

This will make a good faith effort to keep states, regions and schools together.  It will try to spread the load evenly according to how much work people want to have.  And it should run acceptably quickly.

Comment: The reader queue guarantees that the reader with most space will be at the top of the queue. Which should mean if the group can't be assigned to the very first reader, it shouldn't be assigned to any subsequent ones. If that's the case, what's the purpose of the inner while loop and scanning through multiple readers?

Comment: @Ray They are organized by desired_essay_count, not capacity.  The first one might not be able to take as many essays as the second, the first one is just more eager to take some.  (That's how I'm suggesting you get the desired_essay_count to be paid attention to.)